# Is there any way to read data from tar.gz files online without downloading them locally?

Tags: python, request, gzip, tarfile

So I am working on a project which requires specific data from the cosmic-2 satellite.

The data is stored in compressed tar.gz and there are thousands of files so I don't want to download them all and then process them one by one due to time and storage constraints.

Instead I would like to look for an alternative way that allow me to read data from files directly without having to download them first.

Maybe requests or urllib can do that

Currently I tried

`url = https://sitename.com/data.tar.gz`

File = response.get(url, stream= True)

With tarfile.open(file, "r:gz") as f:
f.extractall()

Comment: what do you mean "without having to download them first"? You mean without saving them all on disk? Can't you just save one on disk, delete it, and move on to the next one?

Comment: You have to download and decompress everything from the beginning of the tar.gz file until the end of the desired file(s) in the tar.gz but you don't have to store the uninteresting part(s) of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can read data from a tar.gz file online without downloading it locally in Python by using the **urllib** module to fetch the file and **tarfile** module to extract its contents.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
import urllib.request
import tarfile
import io

url = "http://example.com/your_file.tar.gz"  # Replace with the actual URL of the tar.gz file

# Fetch the tar.gz file
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
tar_bytes = io.BytesIO(response.read())

# Extract the contents
with tarfile.open(fileobj=tar_bytes, mode="r:gz") as tar:
    for member in tar.getmembers():
        f = tar.extractfile(member)
        if f is not None:
            content = f.read()
            print(content.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked up a few options and found this - https://extract.me/

You can use the url directly, so maybe just right click on the link of the file for ftp and copy and paste to check.

Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).